# Why SQLQuery setParameter cannot use LIKE?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have here:

```
Session session = getSession();
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM PERSON WHERE NAME LIKE '%?%'");
query.setParameter(0, personName);
```

I get the following error:

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based!

But when I try:

```
Session session = getSession();
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM PERSON WHERE NAME = ?");
query.setParameter(0, personName);
```

its working.

I need to use LIKE.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
Session session = getSession();
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM PERSON WHERE NAME LIKE ?");
query.setParameter(0, "%" + personName + "%");
```

Comment: You mean I have to use equal and just put "%" on the setParameter?

Comment: I'm sorry, a typo. You use `LIKE`, but put the `%`s in the `setParameter()` call.

Comment: @NinjaBoy: Glad to hear it. :)

Comment: why do we have to put the '%' in the setParameter? why not just put it inside the '?' is there difference?

Comment: @user962206: I'm sorry, I don't under stnad what you mean with "inside the ?". You can't put it directly into the query in this case if that is what you mean, since that will put them outside the quotation marks.

Answer (score 3):

User criteria as

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Person.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.like("name", personName, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
criteria.list();
```

Comment: use of criteria will give better performance over native SQL query, when you use hibernate

Answer (score -2):

```
String strQuery = "SELECT * FROM PERSON WHERE upper(NAME) LIKE '%"
                + personName.trim().toUpperCase()  + "%'";

Session session = getSession();

SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(strQuery );
```